# transposed matrix - how does this algorithm work?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I have an algorithm to fill a triangle

```
set Pixel if ("for".."with")
```

[image: Algorithm]

for a triangle like this
[image: Triangle]

now, Im having trouble with the n = .. what does the ^T mean? It says it means "transposed", but I dont know how to use it in the context of "I am within the triangle border", there is a gap between the algorithm and the understanding, I cant figure it out.

Can anybody help me here? Please ask if you require further information

Comment: dan - don't forget to "accept" (click $\checkmark$) an answer, if it's helpful! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual convention is that $$(x,y)=\pmatrix{x\cr y\cr}$$ is a column vector, and $$(x,y)^T=\pmatrix{x&y\cr}$$ is its transpose, which is a row vector.

Comment: that helped for the Transposed problem, thanks